# Displaying the nested component on the right and the parent on the left

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have component `details` nested in the`todo` component. How to display the `details` component in the right column and the`todo` component in the left column? 
Can I use a flexbox for this? Is this at all possible with such nesting?
Is there another way? Without using a flexbox

Code here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xknr8o

**Todos**

```
class Todos extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todos">
        <Todo />  
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Todo**

```
class Todo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todo">  
        <h3>
          Todo
        </h3>
        <Details />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Details**

```
class Details extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="details">
        <h3>
          Details
        </h3>
        <Paragraph />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Paragraph**

```
class Paragraph extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          Paragraph
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.todos {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.todo {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.details {
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


render(<Todos />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I assume you cannot change the source HTML? Flexbox can only change the source order of flex items with a common flex container, since `details` and `todo` have different parents I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @Adrift Is there another way? Without using a flexbox

Comment: you can use `display: flex` in your container, it'll display the components side by side.

Comment: If you can't change the HTML, you're only left with floats and absolute positioning, both of which take an element out of the normal formatting context (which introduces new problems, like the flex container not respecting out of flow height). You'd have to make a lot of changes and even then it probably wouldn't be ideal. Hopefully someone can prove otherwise but I personally can't see a clean way.

Comment: is this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xknr8o what you want?

Comment: @JuniusL. I don't think so, he wants Details to be in the adjacent column.

Comment: @JuniusL.  component `Details` should be in the adjacent column.

Comment: I correct my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xknr8o

Answer (score 0):

When properly used, you can bake an egg with Flexbox Layout. I adjusted your code a bit and actually ignored the React code. Only the final HTML is relevant in this post.

I added a few rows to get a TODO-List.

The solution is a matter of deciding what your classes represent:

A **'row of 1:N columns'** or a **'column of 1:N rows'**. Once that has been established, you need to divide space over the `.todo>h3` and the `.details`.

**EXTRA** When you are able to modify the HTML, maybe you want to embed `.todo>h3` in an `a`nchor and toy with persistent rows....

**UPDATE**
Reintroduced `width`'s on `todos, todo` and `details` from original CSS.

See what happens next (go full-screen and resize your browser):

```css
/* Relevant Rules*/

/* UDATE reintroduced original WIDTH on below classes */
/* still works, but looks less purdy */
.todos               { display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 500px; }
.todo                { display: flex; flex-direction: row   ; width: 250px; }
.details             { display: none; flex-direction: column; width: 250px; } /* initially hidden */




.todo>:first-child   { flex: 1 } /* either <h3> or <a> */
.details             { flex: 4 } /* take up 4 times more space than :first-child */

.todo:hover>.details { display: flex } /* show on hover/focus only */

/* irrelevant some niceness */
h3                   { margin: 0 }

.todo                { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd }
.todo>:first-child   { padding: .5rem } /* either <h3> or <a> */
.details             { padding: .5rem; background-color: CornSilk; color: black }
.todo:hover          { background-color: CornflowerBlue; color: CornSilk }

/*************************************/
/*EXTRA when you are able to use <a> */
/*************************************/
/*  */
.todo>a              { text-decoration: none; color: currentColor }
.todo>a:focus+.details { display: flex }
/* Will show details persistent on hover>click/tap until focus shifts */
```

```html
<div id="root">
        <div class="todos">

            <div class="todo">
                <h3>plain todo Line</h3>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="todo">
                <a href="javascript:(void)"><h3>todo line with &lt;a&gt; click</h3></a>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="todo">
                <h3>plain todo Line</h3>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="todo">
                <a href="javascript:(void)"><h3>todo line with &lt;a&gt; click</h3></a>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="todo">
                <a href="javascript:(void)"><h3>todo line with &lt;a&gt; click</h3></a>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="todo">
                <h3>plain todo Line</h3>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="todo">
                <h3>plain todo Line</h3>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="todo">
                <h3>plain todo Line</h3>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="todo">
                <a href="javascript:(void)"><h3>todo line with &lt;a&gt; click</h3></a>
                <div class="details">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
                            Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
                            qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You've removed the width on two elements (I believe OP cannot change this) and `flex-direction: row` is not needed on `todo` since it's the initial value.

Comment: It's a tut to show a priciple, surely the OP can read up on FBL specs. Why not come up with a good alternative solution yourself.

Comment: I would like to but the OP needs to clarify whether or not things like `width` can be changed. I wasn't criticizing your solution, instead wanted the OP to know certain things were changed.

Comment: No mention of constraints means 'free do to' in my book. But that is beside the point, with or without the size constraint the basic idea stands. BTW, `.details` IS a child of `.todo`, which is a child of `.todos`, contrary to what you mentioned in a comment earlier.

Comment: To be perfectly sure, OP asked: 'Can I use a flexbox for this? Is this at all possible with such nesting? Is there another way?' without further ado...

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment earlier, I stated that they each have different parents meaning re-ordering through `order` wouldn't be possible? I'm not sure I follow what you're hinting at.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195029/discussion-between-adrift-and-rene-van-der-lende).